# ASP.NET Core Tag helpers and resulted HTML difference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Apologies for unclear title, but didn't know how to specify it, please, feel free to edit my question.

I managed to write equivalent code to given one in Razor Pages:

My markup:

```
<a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-id="@Model.InstructorID" asp-route-courseID="@item.CourseID">Select</a>
```

Which results in following HTML:

```
<a href="/Instructors/2?courseID=1045">Select</a>
```

Second piece of markup:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Select", "OnGetAsync", new { courseID = item.CourseID })
```

Which results in following HTML:

```
<a href="/Instructors/2?courseID=1045&amp;action=OnGetAsync">Select</a>
```

What I would like to know: what is the difference between the two, except different URL generated and what does the differing part in URL mean?

**EDIT**

Here's my `Startup` class:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<Data.SchoolContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContosoUniversityConnectionString")));

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show your routing config code (all of it) from application startup. This is explainable because of how route matching works, but only if you show the routing code.

Comment: when you do `@Html.ActionLink("Select", "OnGetAsync", new { courseID = item.CourseID })` have you tried to specify controller as well? I only see action and since you add additional parameter courseID it might be that controller becomes mandatory in this case. But I'm just guessing.

Comment: You don't have any routes defined there. According to the [docs of the UseMvc() overload](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/760c8f38678118734399c58c2dac981ea6e47046/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Builder/MvcApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs), `This method only supports attribute routing. To add conventional routes use UseMvc(IApplicationBuilder, Action<IRouteBuilder>)`. So if you are using attribute routing, post your routes. If not, you don't have any routes and that is why your URLs don't work. See [the routing docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

Comment: @NightOwl888 Who did say that anything isn't working? Both work like charm :) I am just curious :)

Comment: Actually, no. The typical behavior with routing is to use paths `/Instructors/2/course/1045` because query strings do not normally affect which action method is selected or which parameters are passed in. Using query strings can also work, but the `action=OnGetAsync` parameter means something is seriously wrong. If you are using attribute routing, post the routes. If not, you should at the very least call `UseMvcWithDefaultRoute()` (instead of `UseMvc()`) to set up some basic routing.

Comment: @NightOwl888 That's interesting point. Is it seriously wrong? Because this approach was posted on MSDN tutorial "Contoso University". The second one (which is better, right?) I've written myself. Also, I know routing etc., but for some reason I can't find it... Is route data set to `id` by default by any chance?

Comment: It is only seriously wrong if you are not using `[Route("something/something")]` on your controllers or actions, but we need to see those values in order to explain why your URLs are building this way. Also, if you are referring to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/crud), they are using the routing from the Visual Studio MVC template `app.UseMvc(routes => { routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });` - you are missing the `MapRoute` part from your configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure, the Html.ActionLink will not work properly with Razor Pages, because it is generating the link out of route information and relates to controllers and actions. Razor Pages don't have controllers and actions. So the AnchorTagHelper will work best here.